# python zip function is malfunctioning

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
first_len = [15,20,25,30,35]
meas_len = []
meas_len_ipt = input("type 5 values separated by comma:")
meas_len.append(meas_len_ipt)


for fl, ml in list(zip(first_len,meas_len)):
    print(fl,ml)


input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

I've intended

```
15 1
20 2
25 3
30 4
35 5
```

to appear, but the result is

```
15 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: You take a single string as input and append that to your list. You need to split that string into a list of 5 values for the code to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`meas_len_ipt` is just a single string when you input it. You need to split it to individual elements:

```
meas_len_ipt = input("type 5 values separated by comma:")
meas_len = meas_len_ipt.split(",")
```